# Read trimmed strings from file using awk

Tags: string, awk, filenames, trim

I have a txt file which reads as

```
<workset>
  <description>
    <RVpeak value="-1"/>
    <LVpeak value="-1"/>
    <PreferedRef value="-1"/>
  </description>
  <frame image="IM-0001-0001.dcm"/>
  <frame image="IM-0001-0002.dcm"/>
  <frame image="IM-0001-0003.dcm"/>
...
```

It containts a list of file names (eg IM-0001-0001.dcm) I need to process using the same commands. I'd like to use awk to read the file names and launch my processing functions (already implemented). Of note, file names can generally be of different length. Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should work...

```
for f in $(awk -F\" '/<frame/{print $2}' input.txt)
do
  # do something with file named in ${f}
done
```